# How to add image to ZoomToExtent button in open layers?

Tags: typescript, openlayers

I'm trying to customize ZoomToExtent control in css and set an image on the button as it says on open layers api description, but this doesn't work.

Anyone else had this problem and solved it ?

CSS:

```
.ol-zoom-extent button {
   background-image: url(https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/mazenl77/I-like-buttons-3a/512/Cute-Ball-Go-icon.png);
   height: 1.375em;
   width: 1.375em;
   background-size: 100%;
}
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-27zehs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done in javascript

```
var zoom = document.createElement('span');
zoom.innerHTML = '<img src="icon.png" width="32" height="32">';

var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [ layer ],
    target: 'map',
    controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([
        new ol.control.ZoomToExtent({
            label: zoom
        })
    ])
});
```

It could also be done in CSS but the syntax should be

```
background-image: url(https://openlayers.org/en/v5.3.0/examples/data/icon.png);
```

Full example code using javascript

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
  <style>
    html, body, .map {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map" class="map"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    var zoom = document.createElement('span');
    zoom.innerHTML = '<img src="https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/mazenl77/I-like-buttons-3a/512/Cute-Ball-Go-icon.png" width="100%" height="100%">';

    var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: new ol.source.OSM()
            })
        ],
        controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([
            new ol.control.ZoomToExtent({label: zoom})
        ]),
        view: new ol.View({
            center: [0,0],
            zoom: 2
        })
    });

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Full example code using CSS

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
  <style>
    html, body, .map {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .ol-zoom-extent button {
        background-image: url(https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/mazenl77/I-like-buttons-3a/512/Cute-Ball-Go-icon.png);
        background-size: 100%;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map" class="map"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: new ol.source.OSM()
            })
        ],
        controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([
            new ol.control.ZoomToExtent({label: ''})
        ]),
        view: new ol.View({
            center: [0,0],
            zoom: 2
        })
    });

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to add the url encapsulation but still no success. :(

Comment: If you are using the CSS method you may also need `.ol-zoom-extent button {
  background-color: transparent;
}` and set `label: ''` in your javascript

Comment: The background image can also be set on the button, leaving the blue background behind the image instead of in front of it.(similar to the result using js),

Comment: I've updated the stackblitz but still same result :(

Comment: Nothing in the style seems to be being picked up.  It looks like an Angular problem.  The javascript method does work, but you will need a non-transparent image if you don't want a blue background.  I've updated my answer with the full source of pure OpenLayers examples.

Comment: Yeah the js method works. I will go for that. Thanks.